# To prevent sql-injection, is it sufficient for mysqli_real_escape_string() to be applied only once to a comma separated string?

Tags: php, sql-injection

I apologize if someone posted this and I missed it...I googled and scanned SO for a similar question and if it exists, I missed it.

Scenario: user enters comma separated input. The string needs to be exploded and each piece used to update different table row. Is it sufficient to apply mysqli_real_escape_string() once:

```
<?php include 'connect.php';

$ExplodedCommaString = explode(",", mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $_GET['userinput']));
$Count = count($ExplodedCommaString);

for ($i = 0; $i < $Count; $i++) {
    $myID = $ExplodedCommaString[$i];
    $sql = mysqli_query($cxn, "UPDATE myTable SET myValue = 'y' WHERE id = '$myID'");
}
?>
```

or must each pass through the for loop apply mysqli_real_escape_string?

```
<?php include 'connect.php';

$ExplodedCommaString = explode(",", $_GET['userinput']);
$Count = count($ExplodedCommaString);

for ($i = 0; $i < $Count; $i++) {
    $myID = $ExplodedCommaString[$i];
    $sql = mysqli_query($cxn, "UPDATE myTable SET myValue = 'y' WHERE id = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $myID)."'");
}
?>
```

So, apply it once on the comma-separated string and explode the string, or explode the string and then apply it for each iteration of the for loop?

Comment: Apply to each component.

Comment: You're already using `mysqli_`, so why not just use the built in prepared statements and not have to worry about escaping user input at all?

Comment: Being honest here...I have never used prepared statements and I have read the advantages over mysqli_query are marginal at best

Comment: Then you should read different things. It separates your possibly evil strings from your sql, making it so you don't need to question if you are doing enough. This question alone is reason for you to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using prepared statements you don't have to worry about escaping the content yourself, or how to properly do it.

Example:

```
<?php include 'connect.php';

$ExplodedCommaString = explode(",", $_GET['userinput']);
$Count = count($ExplodedCommaString);

for ($i = 0; $i < $Count; $i++) {
    $myID = $ExplodedCommaString[$i];
    // replace your raw var with ? in the sql statement
    $sql = "UPDATE myTable SET myValue = 'y' WHERE id = ?";
    // run the prepare method
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    // bind the '?' in the sql statement to $myID of type int
    // I'm assuming it's an int here, if it's a string change the 'i' to an 's'
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $myID);
    // and run it
    $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

[Some further reading, examples, and discussion.](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli)

Comment: OK...I'll give it a try